# Как создать List и сохранять там модели в MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Заголовок конечно не о чем, но кратно сложно сформулировать. Я хочу сохранять все данные от пользователя не в БД а например в Лист. Например: пользователь сохранил форму и все данные отправились в Лист и нас главной странице появилась запись, потом вторая и т.д. Когда аппликация рестартуется, то все пропадает. 
**Create.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Create New System</h4>
            <hr />

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.sys_id)</td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sys_id)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sys_id)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.sys_name)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sys_name)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sys_name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.sys_valid)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sys_valid)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sys_valid)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.sys_deleted)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sys_deleted)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sys_deleted)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.sys_location)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sys_location)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sys_location)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.connection)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.connection)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.connection)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.sys_type)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sys_type)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sys_type)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.category_authorization)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.category_authorization)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.category_authorization)
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Index")'" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public class SystemsController : Controller
{
    List<SystemViewModel> model = new List<SystemViewModel>() { };
    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        return this.View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SystemViewModel systemModel)
    {
        SystemViewModel newModel = new SystemViewModel()
            {
                sys_id = systemModel.sys_id,
                sys_name = systemModel.sys_name,
                sys_valid = systemModel.sys_valid,
                sys_deleted = systemModel.sys_deleted,
                sys_location = systemModel.sys_location,
                connection = systemModel.connection,
                sys_type = systemModel.sys_type,
                category_authorization = systemModel.category_authorization
            };
        model.Add(newModel);
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
    public class SystemViewModel 
{
    public long sys_id { get; set; } = 1;
    [DisplayName("System")]
    public string sys_name { get; set; }
    public string sys_valid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? sys_deleted { get; set; }
    public string sys_location { get; set; }
    public string connection { get; set; }
    public string sys_type { get; set; }
    public bool category_authorization { get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
  @using (this.Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>IsValid</th>
                    <th>Deleted</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Connection</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>HasCategoryAuthorization</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               @if (Model != null)
               {
                   foreach (var s in Model)
                   {
                    <tr title="Edit" data-link="@Url.Action("Edit", new { sys_id = s.sys_id })">
                        <td class="centered"><p>@s.sys_id</p></td>
                        <td class="centered"><p>@s.sys_name</p></td>
                        <td class="centered"><p>@s.sys_valid</p></td>
                        <td class="centered"><p>@s.sys_deleted</p></td>
                        <td class="centered"><p>@s.sys_location</p></td>
                        <td class="centered"><p>@s.connection</p></td>
                        <td class="centered"><p>@s.sys_type</p></td>
                        <td class="centered"><p>@s.category_authorization</p></td>
                    </tr>
                   }
               }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
```

Comment: _не в БД а например в Лист_ - вот тут не понял... В статический `List<>` объект? Или как это?

Comment: например так List<SystemViewModel> model = new List<SystemViewModel>() { };

Comment: Так у вас каждый запрос будет создаваться новый список

Comment: А если в методе Create делать так model.Add(newModel);

Comment: Ну окей, запрос завершится и ваш контроллер в текущем контексте диспоузнется

Comment: Тогда какой выход? если он есть =)

Comment: Статический объект `List<>`, только я не уверен, что это правильное решение. Что вы подразумевали под _Когда аппликация рестартуется_?

Comment: Stop iis ==> Start iis

Comment: Странно конечно, по идее данные вообще никак не должны зависеть от перезапуска сервера... Статический объект вам подойдет в этом случае.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо. Если хотите, то оформите комментарий как ответ и я его помечу как правильный =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуйста, познакомтесь с [жизненным циклом запроса](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx), а именно:

> Выгрузка вызывается после завершения отрисовки страницы, отправки
>   клиенту и готовности к удалению. На данном этапе свойства страницы,
>   например Response и Request, выгружаются, производится очистка.

Для того, что бы объект из одного запроса был виден в другом запросе требуется сделать объект статическим. В этом случае он создастся один раз за все время жизни сервера.

```
public class SystemsController : Controller
{
    private static List<SystemViewModel> models = new List<SystemViewModel>();
    ...
}
```

**НО!** После перезапуска сервера все данные будут теряться.